# SQL error for creating table and inserting values in it. Error -12233 and 12101

Tags: sql, sql-insert, create-table, mimer-sql

So I'm trying to create a table in SQL and then insert values into it. However, I seem to be getting this error:

> [Error Code: -12101, SQL State: 42000]  Syntax error, 'CHECK'  assumed
>   missing

and

> [Error Code: -12233, SQL State: 42000]  The number of insert values is
>   not the same as the number of object columns

Here is my SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE Server(
Nummer INTEGER NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY(Nummer) 
);
INSERT INTO Server(Nummer)
VALUES (1,2,3,4,5);
```

So I want to create a table named `Server` which has a primary key named `nummer`. Nummer then has the values 1,2,3,4,5

UPDATE--------------------------------------------------------------------

So my new code is:

```
CREATE TABLE Server(
    Nummer INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Nummer), 
);

INSERT INTO Server(Nummer)
    VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO Server(Nummer)
    VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO Server(Nummer)
    VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO Server(Nummer)
    VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO Server(Nummer)
    VALUES(5);
```

I solved the check problem by simply putting a comma after every statement in the create section.

But I got a new problem which is this error code:

> [Error Code: -12101, SQL State: 42000]  Syntax error, IDENTIFIER
>   IDENTIFIER  assumed missing

Comment: Your added `CREATE TABLE` statement has an extra comma just before the final `)`. Remove it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a table with a single colums so you can use multiple insert as

```
 INSERT INTO Server(Nummer)
 VALUES (1);
 INSERT INTO Server(Nummer)
 VALUES (2);
  .....
```

OR If you want batch insert you should use this way

```
 INSERT INTO Server(Nummer)
 VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick answer. It fixed the second error but the first error remains. Now I only get this error: [Error Code: -12101, SQL State: 42000]  Syntax error, 'CHECK'  assumed missing. What does this really mean and any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: I never see  an Error Code: -12101, which db you are using ?  seems not related  to  the code you provided .. you have other ..

Comment: the -12101 is  sintax error for assuminng missing token.. but your (SQL)  code seems right to me  .. check for mimer-sql specified .. http://www.it.uu.se/research/group/udbl/dbt-ht2004/sql_programmers_manual_82.pdf

Comment: Mimer SQL doesn't support that batch INSERT syntax. I.e. one INSERT per value is required.

Comment: Yes, I know... My comment was intended as information for other users!

Comment: @jarlh you are not the OP  so you should post your question and  not  .. manage the question of others  users

Comment: Your answer, which is accepted, contains two different `INSERT` versions. One of them works fine with Mimer SQL, but the other doesn't. Why am I not supposed to write a comment telling that Mimer SQL doesn't support the batch SQL syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert a list of values like that. You have to create 5 insert clauses. If you're using Sql server, you can create one insert clause, with five values.

Comment: Insert multiple rows with a single statement is nothing special to SQL Server - it's part of the SQL standard

Comment: you can't make an insert into table (column) values (1),(2) in Oracle.

Comment: You are right Oracle, does not support that. But essentially every other DBMS supports that - it's not just SQL Server and Oracle out there.